# Why is my container while loop only cycling the first item?

Tags: php, mysql

```
// current session id
$sid = session_id();

// get current cart session
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_cart WHERE ct_session_id =  '$sid'";
$result = dbQuery($sql);

// get all the items in the car category
$query = "SELECT pd_id FROM tbl_product WHERE cat_id ='28'";
$r = dbQuery($query);

//Cycle through the cart and compare each cart item to the cars to determine
  if the cart contains a car in it.
         while($cart = dbFetchAssoc($result)){
    while($product = dbFetchAssoc($r)){
        echo $cart['pd_id'] . " - ";
        echo $product['pd_id']. "<br>";
    }
}
```

dbFetchAssoc() is a custom database layer that is basically (mysql_fetch_assoc).

Im trying to take the rows from the query and use that information to compare. The code above with the echo statements is just echoing for debug purposes. Is there a particular reason that the while loop exits  after the nested loop?

Comment: what sizeof(dbFetchAssoc($r)) says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to run the query again, since each time you call `dbFetchAssoc($r)` you're advancing that cursor.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_cart WHERE ct_session_id =  '$sid'";
$result = dbQuery($sql);

// get all the items in the car category
$query = "SELECT pd_id FROM tbl_product WHERE cat_id ='28'";

while($cart = dbFetchAssoc($result)){
    $r = dbQuery($query);
    while($product = dbFetchAssoc($r)){
        echo $cart['pd_id'] . " - ";
        echo $product['pd_id']. "<br>";
    }
}
```

Here is an optimised version which doesn't hit the database as much. It's specific to this particular question, though, and would be an equally bad choice if the queryset was particularly large - it's run into memory problems instead of speed problems.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_cart WHERE ct_session_id =  '$sid'";
$result = dbQuery($sql);

// get all the items in the car category
$query = "SELECT pd_id FROM tbl_product WHERE cat_id ='28'";
$r = dbQuery($query);

// cache the product results into an array
$products = Array();
while($product = dbFetchAssoc($r)){
    $products[] = $product['pd_id']
}

while($cart = dbFetchAssoc($result)){
    $index = 0;
    while($product = dbFetchAssoc($r)){
        echo $cart['pd_id'] . " - ";
        echo $product[$index]. "<br>";
        $index++;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this second code, but the idea should be clear enough.

Comment: Or maybe run that query once, since it seems to be static, and cache results in an array or something.

Comment: I'll note that there are probably more efficient ways of doing what you want, but this is an answer to the problem in the question.

Comment: ***UPDATE** This is a solution to my problem. Thank you for that. Moopet if you have the moment to show an example of how this could be handled better please share that if it can help the speed of the whole application.

Comment: Well this specific instance is a bit contrived - it's just listing everything in the two query sets, and the second doesn't change. so loading the results of the inner query into an array and looping over that instead would help. But in practice, the queries are likely to be related - the second one isn't always going to give the same results - so this isn't going to be that useful. In other situations, you could probably pull out all the information you wanted with a JOIN in your SQL. Again that's not relevant to this specific case. I'll update my answer to give you an optimised alternative

Comment: Thank you this is an important business application and I am trying to do things the best way i can the first time.

Comment: Caching the products in an array i did consider, it's just my attempt at it was failed.