# Assigning same PHP source to different select elements

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fillup two select boxes using the result of a mysql select query. I run the query once and use the output variable to loop and set options of select tag accordingly. The problem is, first select box gets populated as expected but the second one does not. It remains empty whatsoever. Heres my code

```
    <?php

    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Could Not Connect'.mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('irctc', $con)or die('Could Not Select'.mysql_error());;
    $result = mysql_query("select * from stationcodes", $con)or die('Could not select'.mysql_error());
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Source</td>
                <td>:-</td>
                <td><select id='src'>
                    <option value=''>Select Source Station</option>
                    <?php  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    { ?>
                        <option value='<?php echo $row['StationCode']; ?>'><?php echo $row['StationName']; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Destination</td>
                <td>:-</td>
                <td><select id='dst'>
                    <option value=''>Select Destination Station</option>
                    <?php  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    { ?>
                        <option value='<?php echo $row['StationCode']; ?>'><?php echo $row['StationName']; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/12218232/413354

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "rewind" data pointer back to the beginning before starting to iterate over the results again. Use `mysql_data_seek(0);` to do that, before building your "Destination":

```
            <td><select id='dst'>
                <option value=''>Select Destination Station</option>
                <?php  mysql_data_seek(0);         // reset data pointer to 1st row
                       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                { ?>
                    <option value='<?php echo $row['StationCode']; ?>'><?php echo $row['StationName']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </td>
```

Also do not use `mysql_`. Switch to `mysqli_` or `PDO`. and it would help **you** to separate code from view and use any type of template engine (like `Smarty`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either rerun the query before the second select box is rendered or to cache its results in an array first. Once you use mysql_fetch_* it has been read and you need to rewind the cursor or just start again/

In addition, stay away from mysql_* and use PDO or mysqli instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the second select box, all records are already fetched, so nothing will happen there.

What you should do is fetch al records into a array before you start the html code.

Then in the html code use a foreach statement to loop over the array.

Answer (score 0):

Store your database result in an array so that you can use it multiple times:

```
$records = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) $records[] = $row;
```

And to avoid writing the same algorithm multiple times, define a function that you call instead, for example:

```
function select($attrs, $options, $selected=null) {
    $ret = '<select';
    if (is_array($attrs)) {
        foreach ($attrs as $name => $val) {
            $ret .= ' '.htmlspecialchars($name).'="'.htmlspecialchars($value);
        }
    }
    $ret .= '>';
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        $ret .= '<option';
        if (isset($option['value'])) {
            $ret .= ' value="'.htmlspecialchars($option['value']).'"';
            if ($selected === $option['value']) {
                $ret .= ' selected="selected"';
            }
        }
        $ret .= '>';
        if (isset($option['label'])) {
            $ret .= htmlspecialchars($option['label']);
        }
        $ret .= '</option>';
    }
    $ret .= '</select>';
    return $ret;
}
```

Then all you need to do is call this function with different parameters:

```
$options = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $options[] = array(
        'value' => $row['StationCode'],
        'label' => $row['StationName']
    }
}

$srcOptions = array_merge(array(array('label'=>'Select Source Station')), $options);
echo select(array('id'=>'src'), $srcOptions);

$dstOptions = array_merge(array(array('label'=>'Select Destination Station')), $options);
echo select(array('id'=>'dst'), $dstOptions);
```